# Call function only for unsuppressed records

Tags: crystal-reports

I use two string formulas in my details section to determine which countries to suppress. Formula1 refers to the Company field, and I suppress certain values:

```
{Countries}
```

In Formula2 i call a function with a parameter like @Formula1:

```
function(@formula1)
```

But the problem is that the function still takes the suppressed countries into account. Is this normal behavior, or do I need something extra like `whileprintingdata` to narrow my results.

When i debug the function the first time the function is called the incoming string is `country1` even though I specified it to suppress that one. How can I ensure only unsuppressed values are passed to the function?

Comment: couldn't understand....what are you trying to ask?

Comment: edit is now in the question, i hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

You could write additional logic into Formula2 to perform the same check that Formula1 does. Something like:

```
IF ({Countries} = 10) THEN
    function("Company A")
ELSE IF ({Countries} = 14) THEN
    function("Company B")
// ELSE IF....
```

Comment: adding the same logic as in the suppressing formula... i mean what is when you want to show 500 contries in a report out of 1000 ? :)

Comment: Basically you're telling Formula2 to perform the same checks as Formula1. If you don't want Country 20 to run in the report, simply exclude  it from the formula like I have.

Answer (score 0):

ok got it your edit makes it clear...

what you can do is use the same supress condition in your formula 2 and pass the value to function.

some thing like below:

if your supress condition is

```
if {Countries} in (10,11,12)
then true
else false
```

then use the same in function 2 as

```
if {Countries} <> (10,11,12)
then function(formula1)
else any message as you wish
```